# How to send a tab key input into web-browser with selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webautomation

I am trying to get this script to send a tab key input after inserting data into entry fields. 
The reason is so the next set of data will be entered into the next row.

[image: Example1]

I've tried using the send_key method to send the tab button event to the browser, but I get an error. Is there a correct way to called a tab keyboard input based on this code sample?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def GetQuote():
    for i in range(len(orders)):
        #description
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/app-root[1]/div[1]/div[1]/app-record[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/app-record-quoting[1]/div[1]/app-record-product-list-panel[1]/form[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]").send_keys(orders[i]['description'])

        #dropdown menu for Handling Unit
        select_element = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/app-root[1]/div[1]/div[1]/app-record[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/app-record-quoting[1]/div[1]/app-record-product-list-panel[1]/form[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/select[1]'))
        select_element.select_by_value('1')

        driver.implicitly_wait(1)
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[formControlName=handlingQty]").send_keys(orders[i]['handling unit'])
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[formControlName=packageQty]").send_keys(orders[i]['pieces'])
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[formControlName=length]").send_keys(orders[i]['length'])
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[formControlName=width]").send_keys(orders[i]['width'])
        driver.implicitly_wait(1)
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[formControlName=height]").send_keys(orders[i]['height'])
        element=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[formControlName=weight]")
        element.send_keys(orders[i]['weight'])
        driver.implicitly_wait(1)
        if i < len(orders):
            element.send_keys(Keys.TAB); 

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn-filled clickable']").click() #generate quote button
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I updated the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the tab key to the element

```
element=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[formControlName=weight]")
element.send_keys(orders[i]['weight'])
    if i < len(orders):
        element.send_keys(Keys.TAB);
```

Comment: I added:
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

to the code and it inputs the second set of data. However all the data is inputed into the first row. Any idea how to get the data to be inputed in the second row on the website?

Picture of the output is posted above.